# Import CSV Rails 3 Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to import a standard csv file and all seems to be working ok however, it's just not saving...

I'm trying to import into my customers list and my customer's controller contains:

```
require 'csv'
```

and

```
 def csv_import 
     @parsed_file=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:dump][:file])
     n=0
     @parsed_file.each do |row|
         c=Customer.new
         c.businessname=row[1]
         c.contactname=row[2]
         c.address1=row[3]
         if c.save
             n=n+1
             GC.start if n%50==0
         end
         flash.now[:message]="CSV Import Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
     end
 end
```

On my customer's index page, I have added the following:

```
<%= form_for :csv_import, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <label for="dump_file">
        Select a CSV File :
      </label>
     </td>
     <td >
      <%= f.file_field :file %>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan='2'>
        <%= f.submit "Upload", :disable_with => 'Uploading...' %>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<% end -%>
```

When I hit upload, I get redirected to the create customer page and I get an error that says:

```
Business Name cannot be blank
```

Which looks though it's not actually saving the data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up the route for csv_import?

Comment: Also, can you wrap the upload in to a model to better handle upload and parse? Since, as I see from the code above, the file uploaded is not related to any particular model.

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling the garbage collector?

Comment: For debugging purposes I would try to use `c.save!` (which throws an exception) and see what happens. As an alternative you could generate some output or a log entry if `c.save` fails.

Comment: I don't think your form is posted to the right action. In the current setup you send your data to the `create` action, but you want to post it to `csv_import`. You need to setup a route in `routes.rb` and direct your form towards it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your validations are preventing the save. In your controller, rather than using `c.save`, try `c.save(:validate => false)`. Let me know how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe `ActiveRecord::Base.save` does anything in Rails 3. You need to use the `create` method. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-create

```
@parsed_file.each do |row|
  Customer.create do |new_cust|
    new_cust.attribute_1 = row[1]
    new_cust.attribute2 = row[2]
    # etc...
  end
end
```

As discussed below, if you're getting expected results and you think your code is right, check the results of the parse in irb. Enter the following code into irb.

```
require 'csv'
path = "c:\path\to\file.csv"
CSV.foreach path do |row|
  puts row[0]
  puts row[1]
end
```

If that output looks as expected, then the problem exists elsewhere in your code.

Comment: That is not true. If `c.save` fails, because the record is not valid, it returns `false`. `c.save!` would raise an exception.

Comment: Well, I'm looking at the Rails 3 api docs and there is no save method. I realize they do some work with method_missing, but it was an explicitly defined method in Rails 2.x. Could you point out where its behavior is defined for Rails 3?

Comment: @yock: Fair enough: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save

Comment: @Bob, either method specified should work...will work. The create method will explicitly create and persist a new model object. Apparently the save method will do the same if the model doesn't exist. They *do* work. Is it possible that your csv file isn't being properly parsed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway I can check that it's being parsed? Sorry for being a retard, I'm new to rails...

Comment: Create a utility program to loop through that parsed_file array and see if the content matches what you expect.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have no idea what a utility program is.

Comment: I added an irb example for checking the validity of the csv file.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. That's really helpful. I've tried that and the output looks fine: I get a list of my data. I guess there's something wrong with my form then...

Comment: What about the params[:dump][:file] bit? What are you referencing with the :dump symbol? Shouldn't it just be params[:file]?